# Add products via AJAX API on Checkout Page

Tags: ajax, shopify

I need to add products to the cart depending on the shipping method. So doing this is not possible before Shipping Method page on Shopify.

I know that products can be added via AJAX api, but I am noticing a weird behavior. The scenario is something like:

On Payment page in Checkout page :

- Add products via AJAX and then go to payment page - added products are not in cart anymore
- Add products via AJAX and trigger reload via JS and then go to payment page - added products are in cart now

I don't know why Shopify overrides cart on payment page, if I don't reload. So looking for a solution that works without reloading the whole page.

To reproduce the bug, you can check at sample [Shopify website for AJAX cart](https://mayert-douglas4935.myshopify.com/pages/api)

1. Add some product to cart.
2. Go to checkout page
3. Add another product to cart via AJAX api ( code given below )
4. Get Cart via AJAX to verify that item was added.
5. Proceed to next page and your added products via AJAX are gone.

**Add Product to cart**

```
Checkout.$.ajax({
    url: "/cart/add.js",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        quantity: 1,
        id: 794864101
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
});
```

**Get Cart to verify**

```
Checkout.$.getJSON('/cart');
```

After adding and verifying products, just go to next Checkout step and added products via AJAX will be gone.

Comment: Got any solution yet?

Comment: @MD.AtiqurRahman No. Did not implement it as no viable solution was found.

Comment: I actually did it some way, I'll write an answer later. That won't be the direct answer but might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can only use Javascript with checkout on Shopify Plus. If you are on Shopify Plus you would inspect the cart and add products via the Shopify Scripts and not Javascript. So your answer is:

- No Shopify Plus, you can only play with the cart outside checkout
- With Shopify Plus, use Shopify Scripts

Comment: Thank you for the input.. I am already on Shopify Plus plan and cannot use Shopify Script, because my logic is based on shipping method selected by the user and that is not accessible there. My only question is why cart products are overridden by Shopify if I don't refresh the page. If I do, everything work as expected.

Comment: If you do a POST then in the background you affected the cart contents. How else would you propose to show those changes other than a refresh?

Comment: I don't want to show them right away.. I want to show updated cart on next page when user navigates from Shipping page to payment page. Moreover, those products does not affect the total price as they are free.

Comment: Messing with checkout is a bad idea. You are on a small island yourself there, and it seems like you've put yourself in a position of trying too hard to do too little to really make a difference. Offering free products based on shipping preferences sounds like fun, but as you can tell, will continue to bring you a world of hurt as the platform changes over time and your hacks are continually beat on as experiments.